# How to read this google components dependencies in this pom?

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I am looking at jar hell right now between selenium and a google cloud jar.  selenium is a bit out of date but in trying to see the versions in the pom file found here, I see no versions...

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/auth/google-auth-library-oauth2-http/0.17.1/

How to tell what the version of guava that it will use is?

I saw something like this but not sure how to run it

mvn -P help:effective-pom -Dverbose

I use gradle so not sure how to point that at the remote artifact.  I can use gradle to see what version it's bringing in, but what I don't get is how there is no version in the pom file and where gradle is getting it from.  I am praying it's not just bringing in the latest version as that would be really really bad and create an unreproducible build over time where if we tag a version of our release, later when we build, it would bring in the wrong jars and could break.  Where is the version coming from for guava there?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POM defines a parent POM, which is

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/auth/google-auth-library-parent/0.17.1/google-auth-library-parent-0.17.1.pom

Here you find the version of guava as a property, which is then used in the `<dependencyManagement>`.